# rally node sdk giving back Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, rally

I keep getting the following error response from node when trying to run a read call to rally:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND rally1.rallydev.com rally1.rallydev.com:443
```

I am using the Rally Node SDK, and node v7. I am on a local machine. It is successfully reaching and logging the 'releaseoid' before the 'try'.

I feel like I am not specifying http (which I was before and now completely commented out the server, letting the SDK default it). But it is continuing to give back that error. I could not find (or possibly understand) other general Node guidance that may address this situation. I am not clear where port 443 is coming from as I am not specifying it. Is the SDK adding it?

If I specify the server address without http:

```
server: 'rally1.rallydev.com',
```

I still get an error, but this time:

```
Error: Invalid URI "rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0null
```

I am new to Node and not sure if I am having a problem with Node or the Rally Node SDK.

Code below.

```
    var rally = require('rally');

var rallyApi = rally({
  apiKey: 'xx',
  apiVersion: 'v2.0',
  //server: 'rally1.rallydev.com',
  requestOptions: {
    headers: {
      'X-RallyIntegrationName' : 'Gather release information after webhook',
      'X-RallyIntegrationVendor' : 'XX',
      'X-RallyIntegrationVersion' : '0.9'
    }
  }
});


// exports.getReleaseDetails = function(releaseoid, result) {
//   console.log('get release details being successfully called');
//
//
//
// }

module.exports = {
  getReleaseDetails: async(releaseoid) => {
   console.log(releaseoid); 
    try {
      let res = await
      rallyApi.get({
        ref: 'release/' + releaseoid,
        fetch: [
          'Name',
          'Notes',
          'Release Date'
        ]
        //requestOptions: {}
      });
      res = await res;
      console.log(res);
    } catch(e) {
      console.error('something went wrong');
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That mostly looks right.  I haven't tried to use async/await with the node toolkit yet- it would be interesting to see if that works.  It should, since get and all the other methods return promises in addition to handling standard node callback syntax.

But anyway, I think the issue you're having is a missing leading `/` on your ref.

```
rallyApi.get({
    ref: '/release/' + releaseOid
});
```

Give that a shot?

As for the network errors, is it possible that you're behind a proxy on your network? You're right though, `https://rally1.rallydev.com` is the default server so you shouldn't have to specify it.  FYI, 443 is just the default port for https traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on port 443, glad to learn that. Resolving the missing '/' didn't totally fix things, but now the entire expected URL follows the 'Error: Invalid URI' response - which is progress! I guess I will try to specify a proxy. I remember seeing another post about rally-node somewhere in stackoverflow that included a proxy reference. Thanks for the help.